# element properties in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new to jQuery. so in javascript you can create a div and give it it's own properties like this :

```
var msgbubble = document.createElement('div');
  msgbubble.marginTop="10px";
  msgbubble.style.backgroundColor="#ccc";
```

is there is anyways i can create an element like this in jquery and how to append it.
Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code snippet to create div element with some css properties and set other attributes using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let elem = $("div");  // create div element and reference it with `elem` variable
  
  // Set css properties to created element
  elem.css(
   {
    'background-color': 'red', 'marginTop': '50px',
    'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'
   }
  );

  // Set attribute to created element
  elem.prop(
    {
      'id':'div1', 'class': 'myClass'
     }
    );
  
  $('body').append(elem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For more info on jQuery visit https://www.w3schools.com/jquery

Hope, this small code snippet works for you.. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery simply uses the **[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** method, though it also has [**`.appendTo()`**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), which functions the same way, although the two are syntactically different.

```js
$("span").append("Appended text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
```

Ass for the actual stylisation, that can be done directly through the **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** property:

```
el.css('margin-top', '10px');
el.css('background-color', '#ccc');
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

A small example of creating a div, setting properties, and appending it:

```js
var msgBubble = $('<div></div>');

// set css properties
msgBubble.css({
  'margin-top': '10px',
  'background': '#ccc'
});

// or set html attributes
msgBubble.attr({
  'data-foo': 'bar'
});

// add some text so it actually has a height
msgBubble.text('message bubble');

$('span').append(msgBubble);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery(html)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery) you can pass html text, which will then create an element.

```
var element = jQuery('<div></div>');
```

And if passed a second argument for attributes, [jQuery(html, attributes)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes), it will use those and set them on the element.

```
var element = jQuery('<div></div>',{
  css:{
    marginTop:'10px',
    backgroundColor:'#ccc'
  }
});
```

To append you can use the various methods like [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append), [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo).

```
element.appendTo(document.body);
```

So if you wanted to create your element, set the styles, and append the element in one go you would combine all of these like so:

```
jQuery('<div></div>',{
  css:{
    marginTop:'10px',
    backgroundColor:'#ccc'
  },
  text:"Some text to go into the element"
}).appendTo(document.body);
```